# Different ways to connect to SQL Server using Visual Studio on Mac

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, macos, xamarin, sqlclient

I am using Visual Studio on Mac (release edition) and I want to connect to a SQL Server.

I am aware that probably the most recommended way would be to create a web service and I understand why.

However, I am so unsuccessful in doing it any other way. Surely a web backend is not the only way?

I can't seem to link to the Entity Framework and the `System.Data.SqlClient` does not work either.

Am I missing something crucial?
I can set it up successfully in VSCode, but not when I want to create a Mac OS app.

In both cases, I am making an app that is "mobile" on my computer.

Setting up SQLite is not a problem, but I am after sharing data between apps - is a web service, other than just being recommended actually the only way to do this within Xamarin?

Comment: You can use Visual Studio Code with MSSQL extension on MAC

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I know - I mention that in the post, I am wanting to use it in Visual Studio / Xamarin Studio with a GUI application.

Comment: Exposing your database directly to a mobile client means exposing it to the open web.  This is a horrible practice and you should absolutely not do it.  Some intermediate layer - typically a webservice - will be a much better idea.  Webservices are not a new concept - if you are having trouble setting one up, then post a question with specifics about the problems you're having and we will help you.

Comment: It is not a mobile client like a phone - but a laptop, why would Microsoft allow for SQL data connections using their platform, but not port that to the mac using xamarin? I am familiar with web services, what if the database is on the same local LAN? would you setup a local webserver within the office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the 'Core' version of the Entity Framework:

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/